# Quadrant probability of non-centric bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Suppose $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribuion with non-zero mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.  What should $\mathbb{P}(X>0,Y>0)$ be?  My attempt gives me an definite integral $\int^\infty_c \phi(y) \Phi(\frac{y-a}{b}) dy$ for some constants $a,b,c$ at some point, where I am unable to continue.  Therefore any suggestion to solving the probability or the way in solving the integral will be appreciated.

Comment: $P(X>0,Y>0)=E(I_{(X>0,Y>0)})=EE(I_{(X>0)}.I_{(Y>0)}|X)$ and you know the distribution of $Y|X=x$

Comment: Even if i know how to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(I_{Y>0}|X) = g(x)$, how am i going to solve $\mathbb{E}(I_{X>0}g(x))$ without evaluating the integral i mentioned in the question ?

Comment: Ok, so i found that the evaluation actually does not exists according to Continuous Bivariate Distributions (Balakrishnan, N, Lai, Chin-Diew) (2009).  Thank you.